# Multiple dispatch funcs causing one rerender only. Why?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using Redux to handle my app state. As I understand, every time I change the state, Redux will force my component to rerender (in simple terms). The code looks like this:

```
const SideMenu = props => {

   console.log(`Render`);

   const { isLoading, error, sections, activeSectionId } = useSelector(state => state.sections);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(`useEffect`);

      if (!sections.length) {
         dispatch(getSections());
      }
      
      if (sections.length && !activeSectionId) {
         dispatch(setActiveSection(sections[0].id));   // <-- console.log inside
      }
   }, [dispatch, sections, activeSectionId]);

   if (isLoading) {
      return (
         <div>Side menu is loading...</div>
      )
   }

   if (error) {
      return (
         <div>Side menu error: {error}</div>
      )
   }

   return (
      <ul>
         Menu here...
      </ul>
   )
}
```

In this example every function inside dispatch is a fake (just to test render logic) and synchronous. I put console.log() inside action creators with functions names to see what's going on. Notice that in getSections I have two inner dispatch. Code of getSections action:

```
export const getSections = () => {
   // this is not async func
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      try {
         dispatch(setSections([{}]));    // <-- console.log inside
      } catch (error) {
         dispatch(setSectionsError(error.message));
      }
      dispatch(isSectionsLoading(false));   // <-- console.log inside
   }
}
```

So after run this code I see log sequence like this:

```
Render
useEffect
setSections
isSectionsLoading
Render
useEffect
setActiveSection
Render
useEffect
```

I see 3 Renders, but it has to be 4 because I dispatched 3 times (setSections, isSectionsLoading, setActiveSection). Why it renders only 3 times?

Answer (score 2):

React will batch multiple queued state updates into a single render, depending on when those state updates were queued.

In this case, it looks like you're dispatching twice synchronously from within a single `useEffect` hook.  So yes, I would expect those two updates to be batched together.

See my extensive post [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/) for more details on how React rendering works.